# Incorrect probability density

Tags: excel, distribution, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'm trying to make a bell curve (normal gauss distribution). I have some problems regarding the probability density curve, since its values are so low. If you look column N in the attached file - I used the NORMDIST command. Values should be somewhere between 0,2 and 0,4 - but they're about 100x lower.

[link to xlsx file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/oo0dcl)

Does anyone knows the reason for this?

Regards,
Gašper

Comment: You might want to include the formula you're using and the results you're getting directly in your question. As it's currently written, there's so way to even begin to diagnose your problem without downloading the linked XLSX file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results from NORM.DIST are correct... if you directly implement the Gaussian function in your sheet using:

=(1/($F$8*SQRT(2*PI())))*EXP( -((M3-$F$7)^2)/(2*$F$8^2))

which is an implementation of the standard Gaussian function e.g. f(x) on:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html

then the results exactly match Excel's NORM.DIST built in function.

When you say the values "should be" in range 0.2-0.4 I'm not sure you can be correct, because you have a Gaussian distribution with mean=261.6379 and std. dev=164.8153.  That is a very widely stretched Gaussian distribution, and remember the area under a Gaussian must always sum to 1, so it makes sense that the values you're using i.e. range [-200,200] falling within around 1 standard deviation will be very small under that density function.

Put another way, the maximum value you will find under a Gaussian distribution will be at it's mean.  Your mean is 261 so if I put 261 in your column titled "X" (column M) I will get the largest possible value I can hope for.  This is 0.002.  And you say you are expecting values 0.2-0.4.  This is impossible given the standard deviation (164) you are using.  If your standard deviation was 100 times smaller you might be getting towards that kind of value.

Comment: The range the OP uses isn't [-200,200], it's [-3σ,+3σ]. So the sum of his graph should be just under 1, which it is.  `=SUM($N$3:$N$203)*$F$13` returns 0.997431165

Comment: Yes the range I quoted was an approximation.  My observation was decoupled from this, specifically that point-sampling a Gaussian with σ=164... will not yield the OP's target value of 0.2, in fact it would yield a value orders of magnitude lower even in the best case (at the mean).  My observation regarding area under the (infinite) integral of this, or any, Gaussian PDF was meant to assist a visual explanation of the distribution spreading out thus reducing its peak value.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I misunderstood your argument on first reading.

Comment: Thanks guys. The sum under the graph seemed strange at first. After seeing your comments I realized I multiplied with the wrong step range, i.e. (+3σ--3σ)/NumberOfSteps. It's also great to understand now, why the max values of densitiy are so low, thank you jcollomosse